# Auto Logout When user performing Action or Idle state - Angular

Tags: angular, session-timeout

I have a scenario where user login into the UI portal the time should start ticking and after some time may be after 30 min he want to see one popup saying that session time out. Here if the user is in active and idle i need to show a popup after some time.

Keeping in mind even refreshing browser the timer should not start from initial time that should continue even refreshing the page or browser.

Any Suggestions or snippet???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try service worker

Comment: any better solution.

Comment: You could make use of local storage. Store the initial time. Upon refresh, you can check the initial time and see if >30mins has elapsed. If user doesn't refresh page, you can use a setTimeOut to check every X number of seconds whether >30mins has elapsed. Hope this helps.

Comment: check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-idle/core

Comment: its for Idle case @katwhocodes

Comment: I'm using cookies and HttpInterceptor to catch all requests made. If the cookie has expired, it is then set to do what you want, in your case show a pop-up see [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)